# Average absolute distance between particles when symmetry is adapted

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

This post is about common discussion in an introductory QM textbook.

Let say, there are two 1-particle eigenstates $\phi_{a}$, $\phi_{b}$, and the position of each particle is $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ respectively.

Assume that these particles are non-interacting each other. Because the QM particles are indistinguishable, the 2-particle wave functions can be given as the follows:

$$
\psi_{A}(x_{1},x_{2}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left\{\phi_{a}(x_{1})\phi_{b}(x_{2}) - \phi_{a}(x_{2})\phi_{b}(x_{1}) \right\}
$$

$$
\psi_{S}(x_{1},x_{2}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left\{\phi_{a}(x_{1})\phi_{b}(x_{2}) + \phi_{a}(x_{2})\phi_{b}(x_{1}) \right\}
$$

Now, I wonder if we could prove $ \langle{|x_{1}-x_{2}| \rangle}_{A} \ge \langle{|x_{1}-x_{2}| \rangle}_{S} $ like $ \langle{(x_{1}-x_{2})^{2} \rangle}_{A} \ge \langle{(x_{1}-x_{2})^{2} \rangle}_{S} $, where the subindices label the expectation value for each wave function above.

It looks obvious, but I have difficulty proving this statement mathematically. I was tempted to think that $\langle{(x_{1}-x_{2})^{2} \rangle} = \langle{|x_{1}-x_{2}| \rangle}^{2} $ is true, but I guess we cannot be sure of it.

I tried to make use of the inequality about the square of distance, but I'm stuck now.

$$
\langle{|x_{1}-x_{2}| \rangle}_{A} - \langle{|x_{1}-x_{2}| \rangle}_{S} =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\psi_{A}^{\ast}(x_{1}-x_{2})^{2}\psi_{A} - \psi_{S}^{\ast}(x_{1}-x_{2})^{2}\psi_{S} }{|x_{1}-x_{2}|} dx_{1}dx_{2}
$$

Comment: There is a proof of the statement you are looking for in section 5.1.2 (Exchange Forces) of Griffiths' book, Quantum Mechanics, second edition. There they assume that $\phi_a$ and $\phi_b$ are orthogonal for simplicity.

Comment: @secavara Thank you for your comment. However, I'm interested in proving the statement about $\langle{|x_{1}-x_{2}| \rangle}$, not $\langle{(x_{1}-x_{2})^{2} \rangle}$. I seems trivial, but I'm having a hard time finding a mathematical justification.

Comment: I now see the difficulty of your problem. I tried some basic approaches but I didn't get too far. I wonder if you'll have to resort to the kind of methods that are used in condensed matter, with a decomposition in creation/annihilation operators, or add additional assumptions, regarding, for instance, details on the dynamics. Unfortunately, I can't devote more time to it, sorry.